# Silverlight binding image to an integer

Tags: silverlight, image, datagrid

I got this problem for a long time now. And still I don't know how to fix it... I'm trying to bind an image to a value in my datagrid.

The field is called Billable and it's 0 or 1. When I have the value 1 I want to show a greenCross. When the value is 0 I want to show a RedCross.

Here is the code

```
<telerik:RadGridView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="RadGridView1" 
                             ItemsSource="{Binding TypeRegs}" 
                             IsReadOnly="True" 
                             DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource TypeRegViewModel}}" 
                             AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                             ScrollMode="Deferred"
                             GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
                             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                             SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedTypeReg, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             SelectionUnit="FullRow">
                <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Description" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" />
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Billable" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Billable}" />
                </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Does anybody have any idea how to fix it?

Please tell me in steps. I have tried many things... None of them work.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer guys. I will share it ;)

First you need to create a coverter that looks like this.

```
 public class CommentTypeIconConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                int ct = int.Parse(value.ToString());
                if (ct == 1)
                {
                    StreamResourceInfo sr = Application.GetResourceStream(
                        new Uri("/COVR.TimeRegistration;component/Images/true.png", UriKind.Relative));
                    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
                    bmp.SetSource(sr.Stream);

                    return bmp;
                }
                else
                {
                    StreamResourceInfo sr = Application.GetResourceStream(
                    new Uri("/COVR.TimeRegistration;component/Images/false.png", UriKind.Relative));
                    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
                    bmp.SetSource(sr.Stream);

                    return bmp;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return MessageBox.Show("Fout");
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

This coverter will return the images

Your xaml will look like this

```
<telerik:RadGridView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="RadGridView1" 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding TypeRegs}" 
                         IsReadOnly="True" 
                         DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource TypeRegViewModel}}" 
                         AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                         ScrollMode="Deferred"
                         GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
                         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedTypeReg, Mode=TwoWay}"
                         SelectionUnit="FullRow">
            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Description" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Description}"/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Billable" Width="50">
                    <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding Billable,Converter={StaticResource CommentTypeIconConverter}}">
                              </Image>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
            </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        </telerik:RadGridView>
```

This works fine!!

If you need any help you can ask :)

Comment: Hi I'm trying to do this with your scenario without success I'm getting sr=null using this approach.

Comment: Also tryed the following without success:   Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/bullet_red.png");

                        BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage(uri);
                        return source;

Answer (score 0):

First of all why do you want to bind it to gridView column instead of binding it directly to `Billable` property. Also instead of binding you can use `DataTriggers`. Here is the code I'm using for the same purpose on WPF, please check if it will help you with Silverlight:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Billable}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="RedCross.png" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Billable}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="GreenCross.png" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Comment: I'm new to Silverlight so I'm still figuring out what is the best way to do this. In ASP.NET it's so much easier...

Where do I add the Image ?

Comment: @Evert, I have no experience with telerik controls but it appears that grid you are using should have some kind of `Image column`. Probably you can google for documentation/tutorials on this column type and it will help you to implement desired behavior.

Comment: There are no DataTriggers in SilverLight